# Print Multiplication tables from 2 to 12 in c#

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Console.WriteLine(" Multiplication Tables");

      for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++)
      {
         for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}={2}", i, j, i*j);
         }
         Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

I want to print multiplication tables from 2 to 12, with the above code I am able to print only one table. I didn't get why the first loop counter was not incrementing.
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's waiting for input after each inner loop.

Remove:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

From your outer loop, and add it to the end.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(" Multiplication Tables");

        for (int i = 2; i <= 12; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}*{1}={2}", i, j, i*j);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine(); // <-- Both loops now complete
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ...that really worked for me. also how can I tab separate each table...

Comment: Replace the `ReadLine` you removed with an empty `Console.WriteLine()`

Comment: how can I output the tables side by side ?

Comment: using the console window isn't the best thing to do for this... but if you want you can change your first loop to increase by 2 (`i += 2`) and then modify your main write line  to write two lines. You should attempt to try to solve any other queries yourself, and if any problems, ask another question :)

Comment: @user3648850 - I've added an answer that will give you an idea of how you can make a table.

Answer (score -2):

```
/* multiply of 2 to 12;*/ 
using System;
namespace multiply
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a, b;
            for (a=1; a <= 12; a++) {
                Console.Write("\n");
                for (b = 1; b <= 10; b++)
                {
                    Console.Write("\n "+a* b);

                }
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```